# Need MUMPS Sample Code

Tags: mumps

I am working on an analysis tool for which I need MUMPS sample code. Can anyone provide me MUMPS live code or sample code? Also suggest some links for same.

Answer (score 25):

This is some MUMPS i wrote for fun. I guess if you can analyze this, your tool works:

```
Q N R,Q,C,D,E,W,B,G,H,S,T,U,V,F,L,P,N,J,A S N=$G(N),Q='N,F=Q+Q,P=F+F,W=$L($T(Q))
 S W=$E(W,Q),S='N_+N,W=W-F*S,L=$G(L),R=$C(Q_F_P),R(F)=$C(F+Q_F),R(P)=$C(W-F) W #
 S T=$E($T(Q+F),F,W\S)_$C(W+S+F) X T S B=$P(T,$C(P_P),F),C=B\(W*W),D=B-(C*W*W)\W
 F G=S-Q:F:S+F+Q S E=B-(C*W*W+(D*W)),H=$E($T(Q),G),@H=$S(@H<S:'Q,Q:N)_@H,T=C_D_E
 F A=Q:Q:W\S S J=$E(T,A),C(F)=$S(J>(F+Q)&(J<(S-F)):Q,Q:+N),C(P)=$S(J#F:Q,Q:+N) D
 .S C(Q)=$S(J<(S-F):+N,Q:Q),C(F+Q)=$S(J>Q&(J<(S-F))&(J'=(P+'L))&(J'=(P)):Q,Q:+N)
 .S H('L)=L F  S H(N?.E)=$O(C(H('$G(N)))) Q:H('+L)=L  S F(A,H('L))=C(H(W[(W\S)))
 F U=Q:Q:P W !,R F V=Q:Q:P+F W $S(F(V,U):'Q,Q:$C(P_(W\S))) W:'(V#F) $C('N_F_F+F)
 W !!,R(F)_C_R(P)_D_R(P)_E_R(F) X $RE($E($T(Q),Q+F,P+Q))_R(P)_'N W # G:N=L Q+F Q
```

look ma, no literals!

This outputs a binary clock:

```
:D Q^ROU


|..|..|..|
|..|..|.0|
|..|.0|0.|
|..|00|..|

 00:13:24
```

Comment: If you wrote that, you've got serious thrill issues :-)

Comment: Using Q as a variable name and function name when it's also a keyword...yikes.

Answer (score 4):

GitHub actually host many MUMPS software, but it unfortunatly get tagged as Objective-C or Matlab so it is not easy to search for MUMPS code over there.  Here are some projects I know are done at least partially using MUMPS :

1. [OSEHRA](https://github.com/OSEHR/Alpha-01)
2. [Reynard GT.M Server](https://github.com/seanwoods/reynard-gtm)
3. [GT.M Term Size](https://github.com/pkoper/gtm-termsize)
4. [GT.M POSIX Extension](https://github.com/pkoper/gtm-posix)
5. [Tetris in MUMPS](https://github.com/pkoper/mumtris)
6. [Juicy MUMPS Example](https://github.com/pkoper/juicy-m)
7. [GT.M PCRE Extension](https://github.com/pkoper/gtm-pcre)
8. [GT.M Digest Extension](https://github.com/pkoper/gtm-digest)
9. [DataBallet](https://github.com/lparenteau/DataBallet)
10. [Source KIDS](https://github.com/OSEHRA/SKIDS)
11. [Software development tools for MUMPS](https://github.com/luisibanez/M-Tools)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any of this will be enough for analysis purposes, but there are a lot of small examples at [M[UMPS] by Example](http://71.174.62.16/Demo/AnnoStd?Frame=Main&Page=a100006). There's also some lengthy samples on the [MUMPS Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS#Sample_programs) page. I don't know if they are stand alone or not. Haven't tested them myself.

Answer (score 3):

VistA is an open source EMR for the Veteran's Administration written on MUMPS. You can download it off of the VistA wiki here: [OpenVistA Download Page](http://medsphere.org/download)

I haven't tried to download it myself, so you may need to install MUMPS to get access to the source. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

Look here:

http://www.faqs.org/faqs/m-technology-faq/part2/

Scroll down to (or search for) the section heading "Appendix 6" (without the double-quotes).

HTH
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Here's "hello world": `w "Hello world!",!`

The `w` is an abbreviation of `write` - either is acceptable but the abbreviation is more idiomatic. The literal `!` is a newline.

Here's a fibonacci implementation, first without abbreviations then with

```
innerFibonacci(value,cache)
  if $data(cache(value))=1 quit cache(value)
  set cache(value)=$$innerFibonacci(value-1,.cache)+$$innerFibonacci(value-2,.cache)
  quit cache(value) 
fibonacci(value)
  new cache
  set cache(0)=1
  set cache(1)=1
  quit $$innerFibonacci(value,.cache)
```

Here's the same thing with the more idiomatic abbreviations:

```
innerFibonacci(value,cache)
  i $d(cache(value))=1 q cache(value)
  s cache(value)=$$innerFibonacci(value-1,.cache)+$$innerFibonacci(value-2,.cache)
  q cache(value) 
fibonacci(value)
  n cache
  s cache(0)=1
  s cache(1)=1
  q $$innerFibonacci(value,.cache)
```

Now - recursion in MUMPS is a pretty dangerous thing to do because the MUMPS interpreter won't automatically convert tail recursions to iterations - so this could easily blow up for a large value.

Here's a little more "MUMPS-y" example, one that actually leverages MUMPS' single data structure, which is essentially a sorted array whose indices can be numbers or strings. Prefixing these arrays with `^` saves to disk. The `$` things are functions built in to the language. The `q:` is a postcondition on the `quit` command, meaning 'quit if person is equal to ""'.

Here it is without abbreviations, then with:

```
peopleFoodCombinations(people,food)
  new person
  for  set person=$order(people(person)) quit:person=""  do
  . set ^PEOPLE(person,"favoriteFood")=$get(food(person))
  quit
```

Now with abbrevs:

```
peopleFoodCombinations(people,food)
  n person
  f  s person=$o(people(person)) q:person=""  d
  . s ^PEOPLE(person,"favoriteFood")=$g(food(person))
  q
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the sample piece of code, to loop though a global, traverse it 
and print the data in the terminal.**

```
TESTLOG
 S TC=""
 F  S TC=$O(^TCLOG(TC))  Q:TC=""  D
 . S LogDT=""
 . F  S LogDT=$O(^TCLOG(TC,LogDT))  Q:LogDT=""  D
 . . S Type=""
 . . F  S Type=$O(^TCLOG(TC,LogDT,Type))  Q:Type=""  D 
 . . . Q:Type'="UPDATE"
 . . . S LogData=$G(^TCLOG(TC,LogDT,"UPDATE"))
 . . . W !,LogData

 Q
```

**And find the below link for some more reference
http://www.vistapedia.com/index.php/MUMPS_Code_Examples**